# How to change axis labels in WindroseAxes?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have drawn a windrose using the WindroseAxes but can not find out how to set the axes to display directions (N,NNE,NE,NEE...) instead of degrees.

I am using Jupyter Notebook and so far haven't found any useful tips anywhere.
Here is my code:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

data=np.genfromtxt("data.csv",delimiter=";")
#removing NaN-s and pulling the data from the array
ws=data[1::,2]
wd=data[1::,3]
wd1=np.nan_to_num(wd)
ws1=np.nan_to_num(ws)

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd1, ws1, normed=True, opening=1, edgecolor='White', bins=[0,0.5,1.5,3.3,5.5,7.9])
ax.legend()
```

And here is the figure that I get. In the documentation they used the same code, but the axes are different.

[image: my plot]

Link to the documentation: https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#a-stacked-histogram-with-normed-displayed-in-percent-results

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using instead of `ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()` the following:

```py
new_labels = ["E", "N-E", "N", "N-W", "W", "S-W", "S", "S-E"]
ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax(theta_labels=new_labels)
```